# russian letters and how to make the page compatible with all languages

Tags: html, encoding

I am stuck in this encoding issue. i have a page which is supposed to be in 3 languages. russian, english and turkish. and in future also in german.

this is the page where i am developing. http://web228.sydney.webhoster.ag/soputnik/index.php
if you change to russian language, you will see the word Register will become weird characters in russian language, it should appear as `регистрация`

as you can see in sourcecode, i use html5 and meta tag is set to utf8. why is that russian word being shown weird?

i am soooo bad at encoding issues. please help me to solve this problem

Comment: It's not enough that the page is set to utf8. Your text editor (or whatever it is where the text is coming from) must save the text in utf8 as well.

Comment: @Juhana, yes, i am using aptana and it is saving as utf8.

Comment: Your content is coming from I guess PHP. Are you setting utf-8 into your PHP file ? Page level encoding as well as data encoding. You need to set both of them.

Comment: and then, if your content is coming from db, set db encoding charset too

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set utf8 charset in your html meta tag. However your server responses with windows-1251 encoding. As server headers have higher priority over html metatags you get wierd characters. Just configure your server to return the right encoding or send a header:

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

right from your script

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, that name comes from the database. If you store text in UTF-8, and your database is not configured to send responses in UTF-8, you need to set that up explicitly by calling `SET NAMES utf8`

You can read more on the subject here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html